# Ruby require_relative doesn't work in Lambda

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've got Ruby lambda handler in which I want to include the files responsible for running the whole lambda functionality. These files are in `src/config/environment.rb`

```
src
  |
  |config
         |
         |environment.rb
```

The lambda handler is inside `src/Quiz_continue/app.rb`

```
src
  |
  |Quiz_continue
         |
         |app.rb
```

So to include `environment.rb` file what I did was to use `require_relative` (which worked in unit test) like below:

```
require_relative "../config/environment"

def lambda_handler(event:, context:)
  #some lambda functionality
end
```

But when I want to test Lambda locally using `sam build` and `sam local start-api` commands I'm getting below error:

> Invalid lambda response received: Invalid API Gateway Response Keys: {'stackTrace', 'errorType', 'errorMessage'} in {'errorMessage': 'cannot load such file -- /var/config/environment', 'errorType': 'Init', 'stackTrace': ["/var/task/app.rb:3:in `require_relative'", "/var/task/app.rb:3:in` <top (required)>'", "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'", "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in` require'"]}

Where am I wrong?